# Joomla/Jomsocial PinMe template I want to replace the PinMe Avatar with JomSocial's Profile image

Tags: joomla, jomsocial

Hi I am using TemPlaza's PinMe template with the Jomsocial community component in Joomla! 3.0.3 Stable [ Ember ]
What I am looking for a very simple solution to having the Jomsocial avatar (Profile Image) replace the PinMe image on the Pins which
uses joomla core for image and profile

**Jomsocial offers this:**
Use JomSocial Avatars
To acquire a path to a JomSocial Avatar, you can simply request a cUser object and call a simple getThumbAvatar function to retrieve the avatar url.

```
include_once JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_community/libraries/core.php';
// Get CUser object
$user = CFactory::getUser($userid);
$avatarUrl = $user->getThumbAvatar();
echo '<img src="'.$avatarUrl.'">';
```

**The PinMe template is coded as such:**

```
<?php if(isset($this->s_user) && $this->s_user==1){ ?>
<div class="TzAuthor">
<?php if(isset($Pins->user_img) && !empty($Pins->user_img)){ ?>
<img class="tz_pin_img_user" src="<?php echo JUri::root().'/'.$Pins->user_img; ?>">
<?php }else{ ?>
<img class="tz_pin_img_user" src="<?php echo JUri::root().'/components /com_tz_pinboard/images/avata.jpg'?>">
<?php }?>

<div class="TzAuthorInfo">
<a class="tz_pin_name_user"
 href="<?php echo  Route::_(TZ_PinboardHelperRoute::getPinboardManageruserRoute($Pins->id_user)); ?>" rel="nofollow">
<?php echo $Pins->user_name; ?>
<?php if(isset($Pins->name_user_repin) &&    !empty($Pins->name_user_repin)){
?>
<strong class="tz_by">
<?php echo JText::_('COM_TZ_PINBOARD_MANAGERUSER_REPIN_BY'); ?>
</strong>
 <?php
 echo $Pins->name_user_repin;
 }
 ?>
</a>
```

spoke with the PinMe people and the cost for custom code isnt worth it and the sites on my local not live
to reiterate
all I am looking for a very simple solution to having the Jomsocial avatar (Profile Image) replace the PinMe profile image on the Pins

how do i make this happen

Comment: why are you laughing at me help me with this simple thing